# Retrieving the serial number of a device using WinRT

Tags: c#, c++, .net, api, windows-runtime

We are working on an app that needs to know the serial number of the device it is running on. The app is for an insurance company with which the user is able to directly get insurance for the device. For the insurance policy the serial number is needed. Is it possible to retrieve the serial number of the device using the WinRT or any API that can be used in a metro style app?

Comment: Unfortunately, WMI is not supported in WinRT.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it exactly fits your need, but it is possible to uniquely identify a device (since Windows 8 RTM).

```
private string GetHardwareId()
{
    var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the device does not only have to be identified uniquely but the insurance company needs the serial number of the device. Anyways, we can still ask the user to type it in