# How To Retrieve IMEI number using windows RUntime (winRT)

Tags: windows-runtime

I have the code for getting IMEI in windows phone. Now i need a solution to get IMEI and other device related information from a windows store app. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

-Regards,
Ansary.R

Comment: For obvious privacy reason, this won't be possible.

Comment: @SteveB - if it's available on the phone, why would it be a privacy issue using WinRT (assuming the tablet/device had an IMEI)?

Comment: Store apps run in a kind of sandbox. Sensitive data (which IMEI is) cannot be retrieved. It's similar to webbrowsers... a website cannot access data on the computer. It's fortunate Microsoft made this decision. I would not imagine any store apps to be able to access such data. A store apps is so quickly installed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found another option to uniquely identify a device in windows runtime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690006/retrieving-the-serial-number-of-a-device-using-winrt